# No module named 'users.urls'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path(
    route='',
    view=TemplateView.as_view(template_name='posts/index.html'),
    name='index'
),
path(
    route='post/my-post.html',
    view=TemplateView.as_view(template_name='posts/detail.html'),
    name='detail'
),
path(
    route='sobre-mi',
    view=TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'),
    name='about'
),
path('', include(('users.urls', 'users'), namespace='users')),
]
```

And this is the error I get when running `python3 manage.py runserver`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.urls'
```

Comment: Have you looked that error up?

Comment: Please show the layout of the files in your project.

Comment: please edit your question with a `tree` command output from your project

Answer (score 1):

add `app_name = 'users'` in your `users/urls.py`

for you set `namespace = 'users'` in project's `url.py`, when you haven't set it in `users/urls.py`, using project's `url.py`'s path can not find `users.urls` in your `include(('users.urls', 'users'), namespace='users')`

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the urls.py from users.

So add :

```
from users import urls
```

This should solve the problem